# Hebrew characters not shown on an HTML5 template

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, cufon, right-to-left

I've been trying to embed some hebrew characters in [Thom Sander's](http://demo.html5xcss3.com/demo.php?cat=html5themes&host=templatesmonster&temp=thomsander) free html5 template ([download link](http://download.html5xcss3.com/down.php?cat=html5themes&host=templatesmonster&temp=thomsander)).

For example, I've tried to change a left-side menu item text to Hebrew, i.e.,

```
Home Page => עמוד הבית
```

For some reason the hebrew characters are not shown at all.

When I add hebrew in other places in the document, it is shown correctly. At first I thought this may be an encoding issue but the `head` encoding seems to be valid: `UTF-8`. I think there might be some JS code ignoring the Hebrew text, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: Strange. I've played it with Chrome's "Inspect Element" and couldn't change it too.

Comment: May be a dumb question, but do you have support for Hebrew text? Are you using Windows? Because if not, it's not going to display anything when you run it in the client.

Comment: I can view Hebrew without problems, and I use `UTF8` for all the web pages I create. It seems that in this case some JS or CSS is blocking hebrew characters from a specific part of the document. Strange indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like someone already found a solution for that. I didn't try to implement the whole solution but tested it with your files and it works.

You can find the solution [here](http://www.htm.co.il/2009/09/20/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A9-%D7%91%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%99-%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%9D-cufon/)

Basicaly you just need to use CufonRTL.js to be able to use Hebrew & Cufon.js together. 
You may find CufonRTL.js at the begining of the blog post or just download the file from [here](http://www.htm.co.il/lab/cufon/cufon.rar)

Then you ll have to load CufonRTL.js and execute something like:

```
    CufonRTL.RTL('#menu a');
```

So the menu links would support Hebrew while using the Cufon library & custom font.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot embed Hebrew characters into your website is beacuse the template is using the [cufon](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/) technique, which doesn't support right to left languages.

> [Planned features](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/Known-bugs-and-issues):
>
> - Support for right-to-left and bi-directional text

However, it looks like there is a way around it:

[Using Cufon with Right-To-Left Text](http://www.isthatthetime.com/code/using-cufon-with-right-to-left-text/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this rule to the CSS

```
html { unicode-bidi: embed;  }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_unicodebidi.asp

> The unicodeBidi property is used with the direction property to set or
>   return whether the text should be overridden to support multiple
>   languages in the same document.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to use:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='Type=text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

Or (as a new HTML5 standard):

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

And try adding this property in your CSS:

```
unicode-bidi: embed;
```

You can also try to display something, using [HTML Entities](http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=hebrw) instead of Unicode characters: `&#1425;` `&#1426;` `#1427;`

Comment: did you even bother to look at the link he provided?

Comment: Thanks, but it's already set to utf-8, and I'm able to see simple hebrew text when I add it to the html body.